# JavaScript - Iterate over shared drives to get file by input string (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 4 shared drives with unique files named 00000001.xml, 00000002.xml ... (like IDs). Every drive has ~350k files.

So, my question is, if I input e.g. 08475398 as an ID, what would be the faster way to iterate over drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have 4 shared drives.
- You have the files of the filenames like `00000001.xml, 00000002.xml,,,`. `00000001` and `00000002` are the IDs.
- You want to search the files using the ID.

  > So, my question is, if I input e.g. 08475398 as an ID, what would be the faster way to iterate over drives?
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

This script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the ID you want to search to `id`. And, run the script.

And, please set 4 drive Ids you want to search.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const id = "08475398"; // Please set the ID.
  const driveIds = ["###driveId1###", "###driveId2###", "###driveId3###", "###driveId4###"]; // Please set 4 Drive IDs you want to search.

  const q = `title contains '${id}' and trashed = false`;
  const fields = "nextPageToken,items(id,title,driveId,mimeType)";
  let fileList = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const { items, nextPageToken } = Drive.Files.list({ pageSize: 1000, corpora: "allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, q, fields, pageToken });
    if (items.length > 0) fileList = [...fileList, ...items];
    pageToken = nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  const res = fileList.filter(({driveId}) => driveIds.includes(driveId));
  console.log(res)
}
```

- When this script is run, the files of the filenames including `id` are searched from all shared Drives that you can access and retrieved as a file list. And the retrieved file list is filtered using `driveIds`. As the sample, in this case, the file metadata of `id,title,driveId,mimeType` is retrieved. About the file metadata, please modify this for your actual situation.
- If you want to access to the file using the retrieved file list, you can access it using the file ID.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)